# Is this a reference to "Ozymandias", from Shelley?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

In the book *Deliverance Lost*, from *The Horus Heresy*,

> Corvax is given, by the Emperor himself,  the secret of the location of the laboratory where the primarchs were created (or at least somewhere that holds this information, I have not finished it yet). When entering the cave in the mountain, there is some kind of poetry talking about Egypt and Ozymandias, written on the ground/walls.

In real life, there is a poem written by Shelley, called ['Ozymandias'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozymandias).

While the coincidence seems very unlikely, I am wondering if this is an actual reference to this poem. While I do not know if this is the only existing piece of text that mentions Ozymandias, the content of the text in the book is very different from the real version I linked above.

So my question is: Is this really a reference, as I suspect, to the real 'Ozymandias' poem ?

Comment: What exactly are you quoting from in those two block quotes?

Comment: @user14111 Are you refering to the spoiler blocks ? If yes, it is to avoid spoiler for people who would like to read it. (Obviously ^^)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a name like "*Deliverance Lost*," poetic allusions are very much to be expected.

In this particular case, the poem that Corvax finds is the *other* 1818 poem titled "Ozymandias," written by Shelley's friend [Horace Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horace_Smith_(poet)).

> In Egypt's sandy silence, all alone,
> Stands a gigantic Leg, which far off throws
> The only shadow that the Desert knows:—
> "I am great OZYMANDIAS," saith the stone,
> "The King of Kings; this mighty City shows
> The wonders of my hand."— The City's gone,—
> Naught but the Leg remaining to disclose
> The site of this forgotten Babylon.
>
> We wonder,—and some Hunter may express
> Wonder like ours, when thro' the wilderness
> Where London stood, holding the Wolf in chace,
> He meets some fragment huge, and stops to guess
> What powerful but unrecorded race
> Once dwelt in that annihilated place.

The poems were inspired by the same statue and published a few weeks apart.  As [Wikipedia explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozymandias_(Smith)):  "It takes the same subject, tells the same story, and makes a similar moral point...."  Smith's poem is less famous but still a fine piece of work.  (Personally, I think the two sonnets are of similar merit, but most people seemingly prefer Shelley's.)  This was also not the only time that the two friends tried picking a single subject and each writing a verse about it.

Comment: Horace Smith later retitled his poem "On A Stupendous Leg of Granite, Discovered Standing by Itself in the Deserts of Egypt, with the Inscription Inserted Below" - sometimes being a good poet means knowing what title to choose  ;)

Comment: I disagree with Wikipedia's claim that the poems make a similar moral point. Shelley's point is that the sculptor left a more impressive legacy than the king, while Smith's is that what happened to Ancient Egypt may happen to us. I don't know how the poem figures into the novel, but I doubt that they would have been equally appropriate in context.

Comment: @benrg Perhaps one of the reasons that Shelley's sonnet is regarded more highly is that it has a more layered meaning.  However, the best known part of the poem seems to be:  "My name is Ozymandias, King of Kings;//
Look on my Works, ye Mighty, and despair!" rather than the parts about how "its sculptor well those passions read."